# Any relevant knowledge/studies about voluntary goose bumps

Tags: human-biology, skin

I'm not entirely sure how normal this is, but since I was a child, I've been able to produce myself voluntarily a "chill" sensation that seems to start on my head and traverse the rest of my body, being least intense in the feet. Looking around the internet and forums, looks like other people but not everybody also describe this ability. However, unlike other people's reports, I don't see "goose bumps" on my skin, at least there aren't any visibly; it's just the sensation.

Does anybody know if there are any relevant studies or knowledge out there about "voluntary goose bumps"? Is there even a proper name for that?

Comment: Related question: [Getting goosebumps at will](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/getting-goosebumps-at-will)

Answer (score -1):

Recent studies prove that this involuntary phenomenon must be untrue. Obviously this is false, in order for research like this to take place people need to spend money. It would be interesting if we could create a crowd sourcing account maybe on kick starter to find ways to bring money into the research. I wish I had more information for you, I've been able to do it as long as. When you go to the dentist, just curious, you don't happen to have two bones underneath your tongue that is an anomaly as well? I've been trying to think of correlations for years. I can get the medical terms, if you like. Find me on Facebook Chris Azzy

Comment: What you wrote is much more of a comment than an actual answer. Your statement of "Recent studies..." should reference the studies.